# Yii2 Using If else in Views _Form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, checkbox, yii2-basic-app

I Have 2 textinputs called Address and Mail_address

I use Jquery so when I input some texts in Address, Mail_address has exactly  same texts with Address.

Now I want to add 1 checkbox so when I click that checkbox,
Mail_address has become disabled or readonly and also it has same value as Address

But How do I implement if else for the checkbox in Jquery or in _form ?

Thank You

Here's my views _Form

```html
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
use yii\helpers\BaseHtml;
use app\assets\myassets\InputAsset;
?>
<?php
$button = Html::button('Cancel', ['class' => 'btn btn-default btn-md', 'data' => ['dismiss' => "modal"]]);
$button .= Html::button('Submit', ['id' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-success success btn-md']);
Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h2>Konfirmasi</h2>',
    'toggleButton' => false,
    'id' => 'confirm-submit',
    'footer' => $button
 ]);
 echo 'Save ?';
Modal::end();
?>
<?php
$this->registerJs('

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("change" ,"#'. Html::getInputId($model ,'Address') .'" ,function(){
        $("#'. Html::getInputId($model ,'Mail_Address') .'").val();
  var first = $("#'. Html::getInputId($model ,'Address') .'").val();
        var third = first;
        $("#'. Html::getInputId($model ,'Mail_Address') .'").val(third);
  });
  
  
});


');

?>
<div class="tcust-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
  'id' => 'marketing',
 ]); 
 ?>
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
   <?= $form->field($model, 'Address')->textInput() ?>
   <?= $form->field($model, 'Mail_Address')->textInput() ?>
   <?= $form->field($model, 'SameasAbove')->checkbox() ?>
  </div> 
 </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to write a change function for checkbox like

```
$('#checkboxID').on('change',function(){
if($('#checkboxID).prop('checked'))
{
 var address = $('#addressID').val();
$('#mailAddress').val(address).addClass('disabled');
}
else
{
if($('#checkboxID).hasClass('disabled')
{
$('#mailAddress).removeClass('disabled');
}

}

})
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I'll try it later. But do I have to add ID in checkbox or I only just use "#'. Html::getInputId($model ,'SameasAbove') .'" for checkboxID ?

Comment: its your wish mate i dunno PHP but if that work feel free to use